# Spotify API data to vk.com user's status

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a simple script that puts a user's currently playing track(on Spotify) to his account's status on vk.com. And printing info about the track in the console.

```
import requests
import os
import json


URL_TRACK = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
URL_STATUS = "https://api.vk.com/method/status.set"
VK_TOKEN = os.environ.get('VK_TOKEN')
SP_TOKEN = os.environ.get('SP_TOKEN')


def set_status():
    params = {
              'user_id': 8573490,
              'v': 5.92,
              'access_token': VK_TOKEN,
              'text': current_track()
    }

    status = requests.get(url=URL_STATUS, params=params)


def track_data():
    headers = {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': f'Bearer {SP_TOKEN}',
    }

    return requests.get(url=URL_TRACK, headers=headers)


def track_is_playing():
    return track_data().status_code == 200


def current_track():
    data = track_data().json()
    artist_path = data["item"]['artists'][0]['name']
    track_path = data["item"]['name']

    return(f'{artist_path} - {track_path}')


def run_script():
    if track_is_playing():
        set_status()
        print(current_track())
    else:
        print('Not playing')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_script()
```

Comment: I'm also wondering what are the options to make this thing used by many users so they don't have to deal with command-line, manual input of tokens etc. Now I could think only of web-app, written in Django for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `os.environ.get` you can do `getenv`.

In `track_data`, don't pass `Content-Type`, because you aren't passing any body with your request.

Otherwise, it's quite reasonable. You may want to expand error checking and reporting, particularly for `track_data`, since you aren't currently checking the status. `raise_for_status` is often a good thing to do.